# How to fetch million of record using mysql query within jquery pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I have more than 10 million data in my table, I need just one column email from the table and want to display a list of of that data into the website 
I have used a theme where pagination is already done without database but jquery, should I use php pagination ?

Please give me any suggestion I used this query

```
select emails from tableName
```

when i execute this query it returns an error

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Total record is 1700,000 [rows]

Comment: You may use pagination (using `LIMIT` clause) if you are not planning to display all of them at a stretch

Comment: why cant you use pagination? Obviously, you cant show 1.7 million records in a single page

Comment: I am using jQuery pagination but still it comes with problem

Comment: you might want to learn how to debug web applications before going anywhere.

Comment: 1.7million email addresses? sounds suspicious

Answer (score 1):

You should use the WHERE condition to limit your requested data. If you dont do so php will likely run into memory problems. Cause this topic is to broad to discribe here directly here's a good page to dig into it:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reading whole table, you better read it in batch, e.g. first 10000 records in one batch and filter desired data into in-memory list; then for next batch, read from 10001 and append data into in-memory list; repeat till you get all data and then render it into webpage; -or- use datagrid with pagination support and allow grid to fetch data and display it in batches

Answer (score 1):

Try multiple queries like:

```
SELECT email FROM table_name LIMIT 1,10000
SELECT email FROM table_name LIMIT 10001,20001
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add

in php file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in .htaccess file

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

It can help you to see the actual error, but not 500 error page